# Why isn't my async react-redux action not returning an object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm still fairly new to React-Redux.

I'm building a single page React-Redux app that searches the Zillow API and returns a listing, along with 3 'Comps' (comparable properties).  In the results, a thumbnail image of the property appears (courtesy of Google's Geolocation API and the Google Street Views API).

So, it's a total of 4 API calls from one event:  User enters an address into the Search Box:

1) User enters an address: Geolocate API is called to autocomplete the address.
2) User executes address search: the address string gets passed to Google Street Views API, which returns a thumbnail.
3) User executes address search: address string calls Zillow API for results at that listing.
4) That listing result is then used as a parameter to call the 'GetComps' API.

I've got everything working in development, except the error below shows up after I deploy to my staging/production environment.  I am deploying to a serverless back-end (www.turbo360.co).

My github repo:  https://github.com/ScorpIan555/thrillow

I wrapped the action below that's causing the error in a thunk dispatch() function and it should be returning an object.  I have read thru the docs and a lot of SO questions and can't see my error after many, many hours.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

[image: Error Message:]

The action causing the error:

```
dispatchLatLngFromSearchBoxToStore: (latLngFromGeocodeApi) => {
    console.log('dispatchLatLngFromSearchBoxToStore ', latLngFromGeocodeApi)
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch({
            type: constants.LAT_LONG_RECEIVED_FROM_SEARCH_BOX,
            data: latLngFromGeocodeApi
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the component dispatching the action:
https://github.com/ScorpIan555/thrillow/blob/master/src/components/containers/LandingPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from 'react-places-autocomplete'
import actions from '../../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { LocationSearchInput } from '../containers'

class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      // Initialize component with address string utilized in Google Geolocate API
      address: '',
      // Initialize component with latLng object which stores latitude and longitude results from Geolocate API
      latLng: {}
    }
  }

  onButtonClick(address, event) {
    // event.preventDefault()
    console.log('Address Search Executed.event :', event)
    console.log('Address Search Executed!', address)



    this.handleSelect(address)
  }


      // Handle change for controlled component
      handleChange(address) {

        this.setState({ address })
        // Log state change
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.address))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(address))
  }

  // Handle user input to search box
  handleSelect(address) {
    (address == 'null') ? address = this.state.address : address
    console.log('address: ', address)
    console.log('typeof(address):', typeof(address))
```

// Call Google Maps Geolocator API, returns an object w/ a lat/lng properties

```
geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
       // Simulatneously, asynchronously call both the dispatchToStore & the Zillow API call
      .then(latLng => this.addressCalls(latLng, address))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error))
  }

  // 1) Dispatch coordinates from Google Geolocate API to store for use in client
  // 2) Dispatch call to Zillow API thru the back-end
  addressCalls(latLng, address) {
    console.log('addressCalls.latLng: ', latLng)
    console.log('addressCalls.address: ', address)
    // Send coordinates from Geolocate API to store asynchronously thru Redux
    this.props.dispatchLatLngFromSearchBoxToStore(latLng)

    // Split address from search box for input into Zillow API
    const paramsAddress = address.split(',', 1)
    // Split citystatezip from search box for input into Zillow API
    const arrayFromAddressAndCitystatezip = address.split(',')
    const paramsCitystatezip = arrayFromAddressAndCitystatezip[1] + ',' + arrayFromAddressAndCitystatezip[2]
    // Store Zillow API parameters in client, to be passed into back-end
    var params = {
      address: paramsAddress,
      citystatezip: paramsCitystatezip
    }
    // Call Zillow 'GetSearchResults' API, return listing results
    this.props.getZillowListingResults(params)
      .then(listingResults => {
        // Capture parameters needed to call Zillow 'GetComps' API, return comp results
        params.zpid = listingResults.body.data.response.results.result[0].zpid[0]
        // Set required parameter 'count'
        params.count = 3
        // Call Zillow 'GetComps' API, return comp results


this.props.getZillowCompsResults(params)
      })

  }

  render() {

const addressValue = this.state.address
const addressValueType = typeof(this.state.address)
console.log('addressValue: ', addressValue)
console.log('addressValueType: ', addressValueType)
console.log('props:  ', this.props)

return(
  <section className="bg-dark text-white space-xlg">

      <img alt="Image" src="dist/assets/img/laith-abdulkareem-96120-unsplash.jpg" className="bg-image opacity-40" />
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row text-center justify-content-center section-intro">
              <div className="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                  <h1 className="display-3">Welcome to Thrillow</h1>
                  <span className="lead">A Zillow Knockoff... And not even the good kind!</span>
              </div>

          </div>

          <div className="row text-center ">
              <div className="col">
                  <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 text-white opacity-80">BUY</a>
                  <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 text-white">RENT</a>
                  <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 text-white">SELL</a>
                  <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 text-white">ZESTIMATE</a>
              </div>

          </div>

          <div className="row justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                  <div className="card card-sm">
                      <div className="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">

                          <LocationSearchInput value={addressValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this, addressValue)} className="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="search" placeholder="Search topics or keywords" />

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>

      </div>

  </section>
)

}
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {

}

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    // Dispatch Zillow 'GetSearchResults' API call to '/homes' route
    getZillowListingResults: (params) => dispatch(actions.getZillowListingResults(params)),
    // Dispatch Zillow 'GetSearchResults' API call to '/comps' route
    getZillowCompsResults: (params) => dispatch(actions.getZillowCompsResults(params)),
    // Dispatch latLng object returned from Google Maps Geolocate API call to store
    dispatchLatLngFromSearchBoxToStore: (latLng) => dispatch(actions.dispatchLatLngFromSearchBoxToStore(latLng))
    }
}

export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(LandingPage)
```

Store:
https://github.com/ScorpIan555/thrillow/blob/master/src/stores/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { userReducer, listingReducer, compsReducer } from '../reducers'

var store
export default {

configure: (initialState) => { // initialState can be null

    const reducers = combineReducers({ // insert reducers here
        user: userReducer,
        listing: listingReducer,
        comps: compsReducer
    })

    if (initialState){
        store = createStore(
            reducers,
            initialState,
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )

        return store
    }

    store = createStore(
        reducers,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )

    return store
},

currentStore: () => {
    return store
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this, I didn't get a response and ended up hacking my way around the solution to keep moving w/ the project.  When I need to revisit the topic, I'll reword and re-ask if need be.

One mistake I did make that was present here and needed to be fixed was that I had console.logs in my action creators which was getting flagged.